# Regular Expression for numerals in java

Tags: java, regex, java-8

In my application I need filter concept for numeric.So I need to generate dynamic regular expression format.For example if I gave input is like (attrN = number,operator="equal",value=459) and (attrN = number,operator="lessthan equal",value=57) and (attrN = number,operator="not equal",value=45) and (attrN = number,operator="greaterthan equal",value=1000).based on the above conditions need to develop dynamic regular expression.I tried lessthan equal condition but I didn't get union and subtraction also greater than equal conditions.I need the logic or algorithm.

```
public class NumericRangeRegex {



    public String baseRange(String num, boolean up, boolean leading1) {

        char c = num.charAt(0);
        char low  = up ? c : leading1 ? '1' : '0';
        char high = up ? '9' : c;

        if (num.length() == 1)
            return charClass(low, high);

        String re = c + "(" + baseRange(num.substring(1), up, false) + ")";

        if (up) low++; else high--;

        if (low <= high)
            re += "|" + charClass(low, high) + nDigits(num.length() - 1);

        return re;
    }

    private String charClass(char b, char e) {
        return String.format(b==e ? "%c" : e-b>1 ? "[%c-%c]" : "[%c%c]", b, e);
    }

    private String nDigits(int n) {
        return nDigits(n, n);
    }

    private String nDigits(int n, int m) {
        return "[0-9]" + String.format(n==m ? n==1 ? "":"{%d}":"{%d,%d}", n, m);
    }

    private String eqLengths(String from, String to) {

        char fc = from.charAt(0), tc = to.charAt(0);

        if (from.length() == 1 && to.length() == 1)
            return charClass(fc, tc);

        if (fc == tc)
            return fc + "("+rangeRegex(from.substring(1), to.substring(1))+")";

        String re = fc + "(" + baseRange(from.substring(1), true, false) + ")|"
                + tc + "(" + baseRange(to.substring(1),  false, false) + ")";

        if (++fc <= --tc)
            re += "|" + charClass(fc, tc) + nDigits(from.length() - 1);

        return re;
    }    

    private String nonEqLengths(String from, String to) {
        String re = baseRange(from,true,false) + "|" + baseRange(to,false,true);
        if (to.length() - from.length() > 1)
            re += "|[1-9]" + nDigits(from.length(), to.length() - 2);
        return re;
    }

    public String run(int n, int m) {
        return  "\\b0*?("+ rangeRegex("" + n, "" + m) +")\\b";
    }

    public String rangeRegex(String n, String m) {
        return  n.length() == m.length() ? eqLengths(n, m)  : nonEqLengths(n, m);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you need a regular expression?  It seems to me that using regular expressions for this will make the solution extremely convoluted.  Is this a case of "if all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail"?

Comment: I need to develop some artficial intelligence to generate dynamic numeric regular expression.

Comment: Besides the very on-point comment from @DawoodibnKareem it needs to be said that there is no question being asked.

Comment: if I give lessthan 57 means 0-57 range. then am able to understand the logic and post the logic in question.but how to negate a number in between 0-57 like(^54).in this I dont want 54 value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on conditions Ill try for union and subtraction is `^(?!250)0*?([0-9]|2(5([0-5])|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|2000)$. In this we are matching 1 to 255 range and 2000 numeric number(union) and for negate 250(subtraction).It's working fine.

Comment: May I know how to negate range of numbers. Eg: I need match all numbers above 50 and also below 20 numbers all. other wise how to negate 20-50 numbers from \d*

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple interface for this

```
public interface Check {
    boolean isValidFor(int value);
}
```

Then implement different classes for different kind of checks like

```
public class isEqualTo implements Check {
    private int valueToTestAgainst;

    public isEqualTo(int test) {
        valueToTestAgainst = test;
    }

    public boolean isValidFor(int value) {
        return valueToTestAgainst == value;
    }
}

public class isGreatherThan implements Check {
    private int valueToTestAgainst;

    public isGreatherThan(int test) {
        valueToTestAgainst = test;
    }

    public boolean isValidFor(int value) {
        return valueToTestAgainst > value;
    }
}
```

And then have a class that parses the given input and creates a list of Check objects. Maybe create an abstract class to hold the check value (`valueToTestAgainst`) and/or make the implementation generic to support other types like double.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my problem.I am asking for only numeric regular expression format like \b([0-9]|[1-4][0-9]|5[0-7] | 459)\b

Comment: I know that, I suggested an alternative solution that will work with all kind of comparisons